# How to print the difference after operation in the rest endpoint

Tags: java, rest, api

I have a rest endpoint like this

```
  @Path("/{person_id}")
  @DELETE
  public Response personDeleteRest(@PathParam("person_id") long 
personId) {

  m_resource.deletePerson(personId);
  return Response.noContent().build();
}
```

m_resource is another service class which can handle the delete operation.
Now in this endpoint, I want to print the difference before DELETE and after DELETE. Which means that I need to access the result GET ../{person_id} and the result DELETE .../{person_id}. How can I do that?

Comment: The difference is that before `DELETE ../{person_id}` is executed, `GET ../{person_id}` will return you something, afterwards it will return you 404.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you want to print.

Comment: It's like operationBefore and operationAfter to see the data changes with this Delete method